# Why would the borg want to assimilate Earth in the 21st century?

Tags: star-trek

I get that Earth was easier to defeat in post WW3 21'st century, but what would the borg gain? I mean there is no Federation or technology to speak of. Other than script writers thinking that it might be fun to have Picard and crew fight the borg in a time travel movie, what is the big gain for the borg?

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/108270/would-the-borg-assimilate-a-20-century-earth similar, maybe dupe

Comment: Similar - but not a dupe... this is asking about the Borg's motivations in the specific instance of the events of First Contact, the other is a general "would they bother with us now?".

Answer (score 11):

The Borg goal in an overall sense is assimilation, however, their primary goal in First Contact was to stop Zefram Cochrane from launching his warp ship and initiating first contact with the Vulcans which set the stage for the Federation.

From the script:

> CRUSHER: Then the missile complex must be the one where Zefram
>   Cochrane is building his warp ship.
>
> PICARD: That's what they came here to do. Stop First Contact.

We've seen the Borg attempt to assimilate Earth before in the 24th century and the Federation blocked them, so it makes sense to that in their second major attack, when they were stopped again, they would change their tactics and go to the past to stop the formation of the Federation and Starfleet.

Comment: I forgot about that whole first contact thing when writing my answer, just going to go ahead and remove my response.

Comment: Thanks, but again how does assimilating a ruined war torn Earth add perfection to the borg? The whole point of assimilating Earth and the Federation is to get all that new tech that exist because of the federation

Comment: But they have assimilated Starfleet vessels and people - even Picard, the 'best' in the "Best of Both Worlds", in the 24th century. Ignoring time loops and such, assume they retain that knowledge AND eliminate their greatest threat - it's a win win for the Borg.

Comment: @chanjoobrown dont forget that the borg have now lost to the federation on a few different occasions, because of this, they decided to simply destroy the federation utterly. we have seen them do this before, to species 8472, when assimilation fails, a war of extermination ensues.

Comment: @chanjoobrown In the timeline we glimpse just before The Enterprise follows the sphere back in time, we don't know that the 9 billion drones Data reads on Earth are the remnants of humanity; The Borg may have exterminated the Earth's population and colonized the Earth with other drones. Even if they were assimilated humans, The Borg may not have been aiming to improve their perfection through assimilation so much as to gain a ready labor force to exploit the Earth's resources.

Comment: Also, an assimilated Earth would likely provide a good beachhead for an eventual push to assimilate The Romulan Star Empire due to their proximity.

Comment: Their primary goal was to assimilate Earth in the 23rd Century. When that didn't work, the Borg queen hopped into an escape pod and went back in time. Not quite the same prize, but still worth having

Answer (score 1):

'Star Trek: First Contact' takes place in a time where the events of 'Voyager' and 'Deep Space 9' are known, so the Borg, capable of time travel, would know that Humans would ultimately spearhead the effort to defeat them. I suppose they come to the conclusion that they should fight them before they have the ability to travel great distances in space - that is, in the pre-warp drive (or actually nascent-warp drive) period. Second to this, it makes for a good explanation for the events of the series 'Enterprise' too - though I don't know for sure if that series was on the drawing board at that point or not.

Answer (score 0):

The Borg are collectors of technology. From the impression I get Stone Age technology is still technology, if it's not compatible it would just go on the shelf. If it's biological tech the same rule still applies. Species 8742 in *Star Trek: Voyager* were too advanced to be assimilated so they had to stay away as best they could. If they could have time jumped behind them to neutralize them they would have. But their encounters weren't successful until they teamed up with Voyager. Voyager was a more manageable threat, sort of.